# program run time (in a loop, only displayed once)

Tags: java, multithreading, time, thread-safety

I would like to measure the program runtime in the code (only the time of searching for min and max), my problem is that searching for min and max is in the loop, and the run time also shows x times as many as in the loop, as I can measure the time in the loop and display only ONE result on the screen?

```
 long realTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < PARTITIONS; i++) {
            final int partition = i;
            threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // find min,max
                    int from = arrayToSearch.length * partition / PARTITIONS;
                    int to = arrayToSearch.length * (partition + 1) / PARTITIONS;
                    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                    for (int j = from; j < to; j++) {
                        min = Math.min(min, arrayToSearch[j]);
                        max = Math.max(max, arrayToSearch[j]);
                    }
                    partitionMin[partition] = min;
                    partitionMax[partition] = max;
                    long execcutionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - realTime;
                    System.out.println("exec time: " + execcutionTime + "ms");
                }

            });
```

In this program, PARTITIONS = 4, so the screen shows 4x exec time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you don't care which result to show, then the simplest way is to print execution time only if `partition` is 0, like so:

```
if (partition == 0) {
    System.out.println("exec time: " + execcutionTime + "ms");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put out of for loop this two lines of your code:

`long execcutionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - realTime; System.out.println("exec time: " + execcutionTime + "ms");`